# Why are my UITableViewCells resizing after selecting an item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableViewController with each cell potentially having multiple lines of text (up to 3).  In cellForRowAtIndexPath I am setting the cell for wrap and any number of lines.  As a result, the cells successfully display wider when there are three or more lines of text (the default size allows only 2 lines of text).

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Request *request = self.tableRequests[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = request.question;
```

However, if I select a cell and go to the next view controller, when I return all the cells have reverted to a size which allows only 2 lines of text.  I do not have an unwind segue; I am just using the back button as provided by the navigation controller.

When I watch closely, I believe the table actually collapses to its original cell sizes straight after selecting a cell, momentarily before the view is replaced by the subsequent view controller.

How do I make the table retain the cell size?

Comment: Show the code for setting the row heights

Comment: We need more code to help us understanding your issue.

Comment: I am not explicitly setting the row heights.  When I set the lineBreakMode to WordWrapping and set the numberOfLines to 0, the cells automatically resize to show all the lines of text in each cell. For example, the first cell has only two lines of text and remains at the default size.  The second cell has three lines of text and expands to make room for the third line.   However, it later reverts to the default size when I have navigated away from the table and then back.

Comment: @Wain - Sorry, there is no other relevant code.  The code shown represents all the code that manipulates the table or cells.

Comment: I have a similar situation except I did modify my custom cells to height 70 and when I dismiss a presented vc, the cells revert to the default size of 40 (i guess)